# How do I compile and code from a Ruby on Rails web server, limiting CPU and memory usage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell

I have a cpp code being submitted by user. I also have input and output files in my db. How do compile and run this cpp code on the input and output file I have.

Additionally how can I restrict running time and memory consumption of the above running of code. Also how do I measure how much memory is being and how much time it took to execute the above code.

Edit I got this below hack working. Now the only problem how do I limit the memory usage of running program. I will appreciate if it would be OS independent. But if its not possible solution for both Windows and Linux are welcome.

require 'timeout'

```
    runDir = 'run\\'

    def code_file( sid )
        return "#{sid}.cpp"
    end

    def executable_file( sid )
        return "#{sid}.exe"
    end

    def input_file( sid )
        return "#{sid}.in"
    end

    def output_file( sid )
        return "#{sid}.out"
    end

    def get_complie_command_line( sid , runDir)
        return "g++ -w -O2 #{code_file(sid)} -o #{runDir}#{executable_file(sid)}"
    end

    def get_run_command_line( sid , runDir )
        return "#{runDir}#{executable_file(sid)} < #{sid}.in"
    end

    def run_submission( sid , runDir )
        begin
        timeout(5) {
            run_cmd_line = get_run_command_line( 1 , runDir)
            puts run_cmd_line
            runOutput = %x[#{run_cmd_line}]
            puts runOutput
        }
        puts "Timeout didn't occur"
        rescue Timeout::Error    
            puts "Timed out!"
        end
    end

    def compile( sid , runDir )
        #make the directory 
        %x[mkdir #{runDir}]

        #get compile command line and produce the exe
        cmd_line = get_complie_command_line( 1 , runDir)
        puts cmd_line
        compile_error = %x[#{cmd_line}].to_s.strip

        #run the code
        if compile_error.length != 0 
            puts "Compile Errors"
        else
            run_submission( 1 , runDir )
        end
    end



    compile( 1 , runDir)
```

Comment: Do you know how to do all that manually?

Comment: as @SergioTulentsev said you should first know how to do that manually, then your problem is just make ruby execute that commands.

Comment: Yes I know how to do it manually. I would g++ -o 1.cpp 1.out and 1.out < 1.in > 1.out and compare this 1.out file with output file I have. But Now I don't have way to restrict time and memory usage. Also I know there must be better way to do than just running command inside ruby. Maybe forking another process to do this job.

Comment: On most UNIX-type systems, `ulimit` can limit the resource usage within a shell and its subprocesses.

Comment: @HemantVerma What OS is your server running upon?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Online Judge in Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656592/online-judge-in-rails) by the same user.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Yes, but that question got closed as being too vague. IMHO this question is appropriately scoped and a reasonable (even good) question.

Comment: @Phrogz Agree that this one is definitely better than the last, but also wanted to reference the original `:)`.

Comment: Your `g++` command line doesn't look right. You'd want `-o 1.out`. Also, I'm not sure why `1.out` outputs a file overwriting itself, but maybe you have a reason for that.

Comment: I have added the quick code I wrote in last hour. But stackoverflow don't like my code I don't know why its messing its strucutre. It showing good on my local box. 

The only problem now is how to limit the memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can create some *run* script with your ruby code, say run.sh if you're using *nix-like operating system.
The context of this script will be smth like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
/path/to/timeout /path/to/your/compiled/cpp/program < /your/stdin > /your/stdout
```

Where the timeout program is this perl script https://github.com/pshved/timeout
It will kill your program if it breaches time or memory limit.
From ruby you will just execute run.sh script (`run.sh`) or smth like that.
For Windows you can use same aproach